# iPhone App runs great on Testflight, but not live

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, testflight

We recently just did some major work adding features and doing alot of performance optimization on an iPhone app (very similar to grindr, blendr) with both the iOS side and server side to make it run faster. We created a new build that eventually worked smoothly with minimal issues on testflight with a small group of users. We were confident that the new launch would go smoothly, the test server files were moved to the live server and then the new app build was ready for sale.

After launch users began experiencing many problems. The most common issues are the app being slow, unresponsive and crashing alot.

We have brainstormed a couple of causes..
 - users that are using the old app build is conflicting with those using the new app build. 
 - the server has problems (although bandwidth appears to be fine)
 - majority of users are in Australia (cloud server is rackspace based in US, slow ping time?)

Any solutions would be fantastic. Oh, and sorry I have limited server knowledge but info I could pass on to a potential server developer would be fantastic!

THANKYOU